# Down-vote vs Close vs Delete: When to use which?

Tags: discussion

Inspired by a discussion in the Water cooler:

When should we down-vote a question, and ONLY down-vote it?

Are there times when we should vote to close without down-voting?

What justifies a delete?  What, other than spam, makes a question irredeemable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Votes for questions

The intent of the site is that you vote up questions that you find value in, or think are good questions.  You vote down questions that you find meets your definition of bad. The idea being that the crowd will bubble the good answers to the top, and the bad answers will fall off.  Even if your single vote is an anomaly is not relevant in the end result.

In other words.  Vote how ever you feel(or not) for a question, how you feel.  It is your vote, you are not obligated to justify it.  (just dont serial down vote)

### Close Votes

When the current state of a question does not meet the standards for acceptable questions on SE then you should vote to close.  The process is intended to be close, edit into shape, then reopen.  The quicker the question is closed the better chance we have of editing it into something useful before it attracts answers that may be invalidated by edits.

In other words use your close vote often early in the questions lifecycle.

Once a question has several answers, consider if the question still has value in its current form.  If not then close the question, if so then try to improve.

But in the end its still your vote.  It takes 5 votes to close and there are literally hundreds of people on the site that can vote to reopen if you are wrong.  So casting a "bad" vote is easily corrected by the community.

### Delete Votes

Delete votes should be reserved for questions that have no value, and no prospective value on The Workplace.  New questions that have any potential to be fixed, should not be deleted.  Until they actually become a problem.  Once a problem with the content of a question becomes apparent, feel free to delete.

However when a question goes stale and no one bothers to try to fix it then feel free to delete bad closed questions.  If there is a real desire by the OP it can be edited into shape and fixed.

And when the community finds a hidden gem that gets or is about to get deleted it can flad the mods for a chance to fix the problem.

What we really should try to avoid is putting the mods in a position to have to exert that power to undelete.  The best way to do that is to give questions time to get fixed, or start attracting problems before we delete them.  Just the potential that someone could come in and be disrespectful should not be enough to censor the question.  Nor should your personal opinion bias against the question being asked come in to play.

Comment: "when a question goes stale and no one bothers to try to fix it" - Note that the system [deletes those automatically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/275243) after enough time elapses, so if you have a limited supply of delete votes, you may want to prioritize other items unless the question is an immediate problem.

Comment: @Kevin - I am not aware of any limitation on delete votes just a limitation on the review queue

Comment: [DelVotes have a limit separate from any queue, the same as CloseVotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that?).

Comment: @Nij I dont know that I could have hit that limit 2x in all my time on this SE if all my delete votes happened in 2 days though...